# POST method of dot net core 3.1 web API not working in ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

```
$.ajax({
            url: Url,
            type: "POST",
             async: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: "application/json",            
            data: {
                'cAmount': '2000',
                'lAmount': '20'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.responseStatus == "Success") {
                    alert(result.successData.outputData.amt)
                    if (result.successData.outputData.amt== 'Success')
                        toastr.success('Amounts updated Successfully...!');
                    else
                        toastr.success('Something went wrong while updating amount details...!');

                }
                else {
                    toastr.error('Something went wrong');
                }
            }
        });
```

I call post method from ajax in dot net core3.1 web api. It is not working

I have added this in startup page

`services.AddCors(c => { c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin()); });`

In configure method

`app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());`

The above codes are working fine for ajax GET Method and not for ajax POST method.

Can you please update any answer for my question.

Comment: When you say POST is not working, is there any specific error that you are receiving? The more information you can give the better we could help you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is quite common, but in order to help you, we'll need the JS-code where your do the post, and the code for your controller.

Comment: In ajax call i got this error "Unsupported media type". But this issue came due to some CORS settings

Comment: I also added my ajax call here

Comment: try add Method eg.  options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod()

Comment: Can you post your action please and Url too

Comment: Can you share you web api action?Do you add `[HttpGet]` on your action?

Answer (score 0):

it has nothing to do with cors. fix ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: Url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'cAmount': '2000',
                'lAmount': '20'
            },
            ....
```

you have to create view model for post action

```
public class ViewModel
{
 public int CAmount {get;set}
 public int LAmount {get;set}
}
```

and action

```
public IActionResult MyAction(ViewModel model)
{
}
```

Comment: I can get result from controller - tested in postman. But calling api via ajax only not working

Comment: Can you show your action pls. I can' t help you without this. Or change your action according to my answer

Comment: @Narendran It will not be working in Postman but will be working using ajax